# Why struts2 FilterDispatcher deprecated?

Tags: java, struts2

In API document I found this

Since Struts 2.1.3, use StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter instead or StrutsPrepareFilter and StrutsExecuteFilter  if needing using the ActionContextCleanUp filter in addition to this one.

Why ? As I know that StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter have some problem in I18n.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

www.nabble.com/-s2--New-filter-strategy-RFC-to18045478.html#a18045478

Basically, the older filter setup was confusing and led to issues.  The new setup also was forward looking towards the OSGi plugin.

Answer (score 0):

- Make it crystal clear to users how to deploy Struts
- Make it crystal clear to developers what filters are doing what processes
- Better enable customizations and overrides by advanced users